# How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt[3]{\mathrm{cotg}\; x} \;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometry

I started by writting down: $$\mathrm{cotg} \;x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$ Furthermore, I have no idea.

Comment: it should be $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}\pi$

Comment: in a details ? tnx

Comment: @Andrej: What exactly seems to be the problem ?

Comment: finding last solution step before the final soluton

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cot x)^{\frac{1}{3}}dx\;,$ Now Put $\cot x= t^3\;,$ Then $\displaystyle -\csc^2 xdx = 3t^2dt\Rightarrow dx = -\frac{3t^2}{1+t^6}dt$

and changing Limits, We get $$I=-3\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^3}{1+t^6}dt\;,$$ Now put $t^2=u\;,$ Then $\displaystyle 2tdt=du\Rightarrow tdt=\frac{du}{2} $

So we get $$I=-\frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{1+u^3}du = -\frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{(u+1)(u^2-u+1)}du$$

Now Using partial fraction.

$$\frac{u}{(u+1)(u^2-u+1)} = \frac{A}{u+1}+\frac{Bu+C}{u^2-u+1}$$

I have problems here. What should I do next ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint, use a change of variable
$u=\mathrm{cotg} \;x$ to get

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt[3]{\mathrm{cotg}\; x} \;\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{u}}{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u$$

Then, another change of variable $u=v^3$:

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{3v^3}{1+v^6}\mathrm{d}v$$

Now you have an algebraic function to integrate, and the roots of the denominator are easy.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), whose relation to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is well-known, and can be shown by a simple trigonometric substitution. Then all that's left to do is using [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to simplify the expression, and finally arrive at the desired result. As for integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}~dx,~$ a simple substitution $t=\dfrac1{1+x^n}$ will do the trick, yielding $~\dfrac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi n\bigg)$ with the help of the same mechanism.